# How to Select and Update some values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains a timestamp column. Some entries has timestamp value and some has null as value.
I need to return last 100 elements and need to update the timestamp to now() only those how has value null, others which have a value should not be updated.

how to do this in postgres?

Comment: Why not use `SELECT`  and `UPDATE`  for this problem?

Comment: UPDATE t1 SET c1 = now() WHERE c1 IS NULL;

Comment: if I do this as @FrankHeikens mentioned, I will return only those with c1 is null and not others. I need to return last 100 entries, but need to update only those who had null as value.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. It could also help to share the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your queries